# Fix zip code polygon?

Tags: polygon, google-maps, zip-codes, usps

How do you go about correcting USPS Zip Code polygons? I have an address with a zip code assigned and recognized by the USPS. However, when I look at the [USPS Zip Code polygon map](https://eddm.usps.com/eddm/customer/routeSearch.action) I see the wrong polygon for the location of the residence. The address is for a newly built house so I suspect the Zip Code polygon map is just outdated and in need of a fix.

The wrong polygon also shows up on Google Maps. When signing up for services with the address, I typically have to lie by putting the Zip for the wrong polygon in order to pass the address validation step. To get navigation software to work I have to enter the wrong zip. My guess is these problems all stem from the outdated polygon map.

My understanding is that Google Maps and other services get their Zip Code polygon data from the USPS which [publishes updates monthly](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/111474). Is that right?

If so, what's the procedure for getting the USPS to fix the polygon such that the fix is included in the next monthly update and flows down to the Google Maps of the world?

Comment: No one has any idea where Google gets their data, so don't put too much weight into their accuracy as a source of truth. I would want to know the difference between the zip code polygon map and the address you have that is recognized by the USPS - how and where do you see that recognized? Another source you might want to check is MelissaData Address Verify, which we're using, and uses USPS data: http://www.melissadata.com/Lookups/AddressVerify.asp

Comment: I used https://tools.usps.com/zip-code-lookup.htm?byaddress to verify the address' Zip Code. melissadata.com verifies it as well.

Comment: To be more specific, everything in this neighborhood (https://goo.gl/maps/4LpBrqboHE52) is assigned the 80238 Zip by the USPS while physically existing in the 80239 USPS and Google Maps polygons.